# Cascade type remove not removing records from child table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am working on a spring mvc in which I have a trip stop model and an item transaction model. Following is my trip stop model:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="TripStop")
public class TripStopModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name="tripstopid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer tripStopId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tripStopModel", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<ItemTransactionModel> itemTransactionModelList;
}
```

Following is my item transaction model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="itemTx")
public class ItemTransactionModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="itemTxid")
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer itemTxId;

    @Column(name="itemcode")
    private String itemCode;

    @Column(name="weight")
    private String weight;

    @Column(name="bagcount")
    private Integer bagCount;   

    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="tripstopid")
    private TripStopModel tripStopModel;
}
```

itemtx table is child table of tripstop. I want that whenever a record gets deleted from tripstop table, its child records from itemtx table should get deleted automatically. That's why I am using cascade type remove. But it is not working. Following is delete trip stop model code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(tripStopModel);
```

Comment: No exception is coming.

Comment: So, neither `TripStopmodel` nor `ItemTransactionModel` got deleted from database?

Comment: trip stop model got deleted, but not ItemTransactionModel.

Comment: What about database referential integrity? Do you have foreign keys in database? `tripstopid` in `ItemTransactionModel` targets `TripStopModel` so delete should fail with an exception. Are you sure there is nothing in the log files?

Comment: tripstopid column is in item transactional table. No exception is coming in logs.

Comment: Exactly. After deletion, `tripstopid` will point to non existing row, which is not a valid database state, and isn't possible if foreign keys are in place.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: For this specific problem, add a foreign key in database from `itemTx.tripstopid` to `TripStop.tripstopid`.Delete should fail with an exception, or if you are lucky and everything else is set up ok, it might actually start working.

Comment: I have added foreign key. Now it is showing exception on deleting tripstop.

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement